# How can get a reference to an NSWindow created in a xib file?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I use a xib file to show an `NSWindow` named mainWindow - now I want to get a reference to mainWindow via code (e.g. `NSWindow *mainWindow`). I can't find anything in the documentation, any pointers?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking - I assume English isn't your first language but can you try again? If someone can understand your question, they will edit it into correct English, but at the moment that's not possible.

Comment: You have the pointer to it already? In your AppDelegate class you will be creating the window and as such have a reference to it there?

Comment: Thanks for reply , The MainWindow was show by xib file,just like mainwinow.xib,now i can't get the mainwindow pointer ,i am new to cocoa ,and now the AppDelegate interface is empty, How can i implement    the AppDelegate to get the mainWindow pointer in the xib file?Thanks

Comment: Do you have any `IBOutlet`s in your code?

Comment: Thanks for reply ,i will try as what you said.

Answer (score 2):

The xib file will have placeholder objects in it for the app delegate and / or the file's owner.

On the assumption that it has the app delegate in it, you can get a reference to the window or any object in the xib by

1. Declare a property in the app delegate of the right type and with IBOutlet as part of its type:

   ```
   @property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow* theWindow;
   ```
2. Locate the app delegate object in the xib.  Click and drag it while the control key is pressed.  You should get a line between the mouse pointer and the object.
3. Drag on to the window and release the mouse button.
4. You should see a list of the outlets in the app delegate.  Select `theWindow` and your done.