# How to color the title bar of the OS X app with swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

[image: Example]

I am using Xcode 7.2.1 with Swift 2 to develop OS X app. I want the app to be filled with colour. How do I do it as on the example picture above?

I did this to get rid of the title bar:

```
  override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

   self.view.wantsLayer = true


    self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    self.view.window?.movableByWindowBackground = true
    self.view.window?.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden

}
```

Comment: You accepted mangerlahn's answer; how did you get back the minimise buttons?

Comment: To get buttons back remove the line `self.view.window?.styleMask = NSWindowStyleMask.texturedBackground` @minseong this is for the updated swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Alternative**

If you want to only set a background color for the whole NSWindow and hide the title bar, you can set its styleMask to textured:

```
self.view.window?.styleMask = NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask
self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor()
```

The advantage of this: It is backwards compatible to at least OS X 10.6

Comment: Thanks, it works. But then I loose close, minimise buttons. How do I get them back?

Comment: @minseong usually right before you show the window. So a WindowControllers windowDidLoad would be appropriate

Comment: I need to look this up. Maybe @Grinch can help out?

Comment: The  easiest solution is to set the window to textured in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

If I move your "get rid of the title bar" code to the `AppDelegate` and sets the `window.backgroundColor` like so:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window.movableByWindowBackground = true
        window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden
        window.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor()

        let viewController = ViewController()
        window.contentViewController = viewController
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

And then just set the color in the view controller as well:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.wantsLayer = true
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor
}
```

I end up with this window
[image]

The funny thing is that I have to set the color in both places, so maybe the solution @joshua-nozzi suggests is a safer bet

Comment: Sorry, I am really a beginner with programming. When I add the code you wrote to the AppDelegate.swift, compiler complains that 'window' is an unresolved identifier.

Comment: OK. I have an outlet to window of type NSWindow, and it seems you don't. What does your `AppDelegate` look like?

Comment: Well, I never used it before, so it's blank :-)

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit complicated to set up, or at least explain here in the comments :-) I found this link that explains to set up the outlet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814562/how-can-get-a-reference-to-an-nswindow-created-in-a-xib-file It's in Objective C, but I have updated my answer so you can see how to define an outlet in Swift. Hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this in your AppDelegate after the window creation:

```
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
window.backgroundColor = .red
```

Tested with OSX 10.15 and a project created as a SwiftUI app.

Answer (score -2):

Add a custom subview with your background color. Or (better) set that custom view as your window's content view.